# How to make a for loop variable const with the exception of the increment statement?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, variables, constants

Consider a standard for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
{
   // do something with i
}
```

I want to prevent the variable `i` from being modified in the body of the `for` loop.

However, I cannot declare `i` as `const` as this makes the increment statement invalid. Is there a way to make `i` a `const` variable outside of the increment statement?

Comment: I believe there is no way to do this

Comment: You would need to hide the variable from the loop body, perhaps change to something like `while(i_copy = loop()) { }`

Comment: You can make a constant reference to it in the loop body, e.g. `const int& i_safe = i`. Your compiler should elide any indirection.

Comment: @Brian  That still leaves `i` vulnerable to the malicious loop body.

Comment: I assume a solution that gets rid of `i` is no good? You want to have read only access to `i` in the loop?

Comment: I had always wanted to propose `for({int i=0; i<10; ++i}){` for this, but have never had the courage to suggest it to the standards committee, or to Bjarne when he's doing an honest day's work at Morgan Stanley. Of course my suggestion would not allow you to even access `i` in the body.

Comment: If you stay silent, nothing will ever change.  Unless he is going to whip you and throw you out of the university for making a good suggestion (if so, what are you doing there?), then nothing ventured, nothing gained.

Comment: This sounds like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: Turn the body of your for-loop into a function with a `const int i` argument. The mutability of the index is only exposed where it's needed and you can use the `inline` keyword to make it have no effect on the compiled output.

Comment: What (or rather, who) could possibly change the value of the index besides.... you? Do you distrust yourself? Maybe a co-worker? I agree with @PeteBecker.

Comment: @Z4-tier Yes, of course I distrust myself. I know that I make mistakes. Every good programmer knows. That's why we have things like `const` to begin with.

Comment: If you want to avoid errors, then you should not use indexed for loops at all as they are subject to off by one errors.

Comment: In practice, it should never be a problem. If your loop is small, then it is easy to see that `ì` is modified in the loop. If you loop is large, then it should be refactored into a function.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

From c++20, you can use [ranges::views::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) like this:

```
for (int const i : std::views::iota(0, 10))
{
   std::cout << i << " ";  // ok
   i = 42;                 // error
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bnncvs).

---

From c++11, you can also use the following technique, which uses an IIILE (immediately invoked inline lambda expression):

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) [&,i] {
    std::cout << i << " ";  // ok, i is readable
    i = 42;                 // error, i is captured by non-mutable copy
    x++;                    // ok, x is captured by mutable reference
}();     // IIILE
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/433fP8).

Note that `[&,i]` means that `i` is captured by non-mutable copy, and everything else is captured by mutable reference. The `();` at the end of the loop simply means that the lambda is invoked immediately.

Comment: Almost calls for a special for loop construct since what this offers is a safer alternative to a very, very common construct.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Well, now that there's library support for this feature, it won't be worth adding it as a core language feature.

Comment: Fair, though almost all my real work is still C or C++11 at most.  I study just in case it matters in the future for me...

Comment: The C++11 trick you added with the lambda is neat, but wouldn't be practical in most workplaces I have been in. Static analysis would complain on the generalized `&` capture, which would force capturing each reference explicitly -- which makes this quite cumbersome. I also suspect that this could lead to easy bugs where an author forgets the `()`, making the code never get invoked. This is easily small enough to miss in code-review as well.

Comment: is it an IIILE if it doesn't initialise anything? surely one too many 'I's

Comment: While technically, lambda is a nice solution to the problem, in practice you have more chances of doing an error in it that the improbable error of modifying `i` by mistake. And the code is harder to understand for the majority of readers.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I'm not sure I see the issues you're pointing out. clang at least will [warn](https://godbolt.org/z/oo1Wf4) if you miss the `()`. Also the static analysis warning seems wrong; the body of the loop in OP's code should have access to *exactly* the same variables as a result of `&` capture in the lambda.

Comment: @Phil1970 I understand the issue with most readers not being aware of the idiom, but what "error"s are you referring to exactly? Can you show some potential pitfall?

Comment: @cigien Static analysis tools like [SonarQube](https://rules.sonarsource.com/cpp/RSPEC-3608) and cppcheck flag general captures like `[&]` because these conflict with coding standards like AUTOSAR (Rule A5-1-2), HIC++, and I think also MISRA (not sure). It's not that it's not correct; it's that organizations ban this type of code to be compliant with standards. As for the `()`, the newest [gcc version does not flag this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qxWW3z) even with `-Wextra`. I still think the approach is neat; it just doesn't work for many organizations.

Comment: I know the SonarQube rule I linked states that there is no harm if it's used immediately; however in practice I've seen it flag _any_ uses of `[&]` in different environments. It's possible that this might be from extra rules being set up for the coding standards compliance I mentioned above. Also the fact that `gcc` does not warn when not immediately invoking a lambda I think is one such potential downfall that @Phil1970 may have been referring to

Answer (score 46):

For anyone that likes Cigien's `std::views::iota` answer but isn't working in C++20 or above, it's rather straightforward to implement a simplified and lightweight version of `std::views::iota` compatible [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) or above.

All it requires is:

- A basic "[LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)" type (something that defines `operator++` and `operator*`) that wraps an integral value (e.g. an `int`)
- Some "range"-like class that has `begin()` and `end()` that returns the above iterators. This will allow it to work in range-based `for` loops

A simplified version of this could be:

```cpp
#include <iterator>

// This is just a class that wraps an 'int' in an iterator abstraction
// Comparisons compare the underlying value, and 'operator++' just
// increments the underlying int
class counting_iterator
{
public:
    // basic iterator boilerplate
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = int;
    using reference  = int;
    using pointer    = int*;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    // Constructor / assignment
    constexpr explicit counting_iterator(int x) : m_value{x}{}
    constexpr counting_iterator(const counting_iterator&) = default;
    constexpr counting_iterator& operator=(const counting_iterator&) = default;

    // "Dereference" (just returns the underlying value)
    constexpr reference operator*() const { return m_value; }
    constexpr pointer operator->() const { return &m_value; }

    // Advancing iterator (just increments the value)
    constexpr counting_iterator& operator++() {
        m_value++;
        return (*this);
    }
    constexpr counting_iterator operator++(int) {
        const auto copy = (*this);
        ++(*this);
        return copy;
    }

    // Comparison
    constexpr bool operator==(const counting_iterator& other) const noexcept {
        return m_value == other.m_value;
    }
    constexpr bool operator!=(const counting_iterator& other) const noexcept {
        return m_value != other.m_value;
    }
private:
    int m_value;
};

// Just a holder type that defines 'begin' and 'end' for
// range-based iteration. This holds the first and last element
// (start and end of the range)
// The begin iterator is made from the first value, and the
// end iterator is made from the second value.
struct iota_range
{
    int first;
    int last;
    constexpr counting_iterator begin() const { return counting_iterator{first}; }
    constexpr counting_iterator end() const { return counting_iterator{last}; }
};

// A simple helper function to return the range
// This function isn't strictly necessary, you could just construct
// the 'iota_range' directly
constexpr iota_range iota(int first, int last)
{
    return iota_range{first, last};
}
```

I've defined the above with `constexpr` where it's supported, but for earlier versions of C++ like C++11/14, you may need to remove `constexpr` where it is not legal in those versions to do so.

The above boilerplate enables the following code to work in pre-C++20:

```cpp
for (int const i : iota(0, 10))
{
   std::cout << i << " ";  // ok
   i = 42;                 // error
}
```

Which will generate the [same assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dxdbdv) as the C++20 `std::views::iota` solution and the classic `for`-loop solution when optimized.

This works with any C++11-compliant compilers (e.g. compilers like `gcc-4.9.4`) and still produces [nearly identical assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GcYc35) to a basic `for`-loop counterpart.

**Note:** The `iota` helper function is just for feature-parity with the C++20 `std::views::iota` solution; but realistically, you could also directly construct an `iota_range{...}` instead of calling `iota(...)`. The former just presents an easy upgrade path if a user wishes to switch to C++20 in the future.

Comment: It requires a bit of boilerplate, but it's actually not all that complicated in terms of what it's doing. It's actually just a basic iterator pattern, but wrapping an `int`, then creating a "range" class to return the begin/end

Comment: Not super important, but I also added a c++11 solution that no one else posted, so you might want to reword the first line of your answer slightly :)

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted, but I'd appreciate some feedback if you feel that my answer is unsatisfactory so that I may improve upon it. Downvoting is a great way to show that you feel an answer does not adequately address the question, but in this case there are no existing criticisms or obvious faults in the answer for which I may improve.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I got a DV at the same time too, and they didn't comment on why either :( Guess someone doesn't like the range abstractions. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: "assembly" is a mass noun like "luggage" or "water".  The normal phrasing would be "will compile to the same *assembly* as the C++20 ...".  The compiler's asm output for a single function isn't *a* singular assembly, it's "assembly" (a sequence of assembly-language instructions).

Comment: @PeterCordes - Just as the plural of water is waters, the plural of assembly is assemblies. The word *assembly* as used here is typically viewed as sbeing horthand for assembly language instruction, in which case perhaps assemblies would be better as a plural. But it could also be viewed as shorthand for a collection (aka an assembly) of assembly language instructions, in which case the correct term is indeed assembly.

Comment: @Human-Compiler - Random drive-by downvotes for good answers with nary a comment for the downvote are regular occurrences across the StackExchange network.

Comment: My only criticism is that the function `iota` conflicts with the c++11 function template `std::iota`, which does something very different. The solution is to add a constructor to your `iota_range` class. While this conflicts with the c++20 `std::iota_range`, your `iota_range` and the c++20 `std::iota_range` accomplish pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Right, there's a countable-noun form of the word "assembly" in English, to describe an assembly of things.  In computing, you can have "a .NET assembly"; note the indefinite article "a" there; you can have multiple .NET assemblies.  But in the context of the assembly-language output from a compiler, it's a mass noun not singular.  Consider a C++ compiler that compiles to C: if you talk about it's output, you might say "these two C++ sources result in the same C", not "the same Cs".  "Assembly language" is based on an uncountable form.

Comment: @PeterCordes I used the term "assemblies" in this case because I was referring the output of assembly code from two different sources; the C++20 optimized `std::views::Iota` and the idiomatic `for` loop. I think in this case either "Same assembly as" or "same assemblies as" are both lexically correct, though upon rereading it, I can see why it sounds off

Comment: @DavidHammen I agree with the comment with your `iota` conflicting, but `std::views::iota` also conflicts with `std::iota`. I mostly just added this for parity with the C++20 equivalent -- but otherwise i completely agree that the function is entirely superficial and could be done with just the range. I figured it was easier to present a solution with identical characteristics to an established standard answer, since it presents a more clear upgrade solution if a project adopts newer standards.

Answer (score 28):

The KISS version...

```
for (int _i = 0; _i < 10; ++_i) {
    const int i = _i;

    // use i here
}
```

If your use case is just to prevent accidental modification of the loop index then this should make such a bug obvious. (If you want to prevent *intentional* modification, well, good luck...)

Comment: I think you teach the wrong lesson to use magical identifiers which start with `_`. And a bit of explanation (e.g. scope) would be helpful. Otherwise, yes, nicely KISSy.

Comment: Calling the "hidden" variable `i_` would be more compliant.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. The loop variable is `_i` which is still modifiable in the loop.

Comment: @cigien: IMO, this partial solution is as far as it's worth going without C++20 `std::views::iota` for a fully bulletproof way.  The text of the answer explains its limitations and how it attempts to answer the question.  A bunch of over-complicated C++11 makes the cure worse than the disease in terms of easy to read, easily maintainable, IMO.  This is still very easy to read for everyone who knows C++, and seems reasonable as an idiom.  (But should avoid leading-underscore names.)

Comment: @Yunnosch only `_Uppercase` and `double__underscore` identifiers are reserved. `_lowercase` identifiers are only reserved in the global scope.

Answer (score 13):

Couldn't you just move some or all the content of your for loop in a function that accepts i as a const?

Its less optimal than some solutions proposed, but if possible this is quite simple to do.

Edit: Just an example as I tend to be unclear.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
{
   looper( i );
}

void looper ( const int v )
{
    // do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you do not have access to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), typical makeover using a function

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> // std::iota

std::vector<int> makeRange(const int start, const int end) noexcept
{
   std::vector<int> vecRange(end - start);
   std::iota(vecRange.begin(), vecRange.end(), start);
   return vecRange;
}
```

now you could

```
for (const int i : makeRange(0, 10))
{
   std::cout << i << " ";  // ok
   //i = 100;              // error
}
```

**([See a Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7G57nP))**

---

**Update**: Inspired from the *@Human-Compiler*'s comment, I was wondering weather the given answers have any difference in the case of performance. It turn out that, except for this approach, for all other approaches surprisingly have same performance (for the range `[0, 10)`). The `std::vector` approach is the worst.

[image]

**([See Online Quick-Bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/RAW26u2nNTCWZDuB7QtQ70A6VNM))**

Comment: Although this works for pre-c++20, this has a pretty large amount of overhead since it requires using `vector`. If the range is very large, this could be bad.

Comment: @Human-Compiler: A `std::vector` is pretty terrible on a relative scale if the range is small, too, and could be very bad if this was supposed to be a small inner loop that ran many many times.  Some compilers (like clang with libc++, but not libstdc++) can optimize away new/delete of an allocation that doesn't escape the function, but otherwise this could easily be the difference between a small fully-unrolled loop vs. a call to `new` + `delete`, and maybe actually storing into that memory.

Comment: IMO, the minor benefit of `const i` is simply not worth the overhead for most cases, without C++20 ways that make it cheap.  Especially with runtime-variable ranges that make it less likely for the compiler to optimize everything away.

Answer (score 10):

And here is a C++11 version:

```
for (int const i : {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10})
{
    std::cout << i << " ";
    // i = 42; // error
}
```

[Here is live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4EE3e5)

Comment: This doesn't scale if the max number is decided by a runtime value.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Simply extend the list to the desired value and recompile your entire program dynamically ;)

Comment: You didn't mention what is the case of `{..}`. You need to include something to get this feature active. For example, your code will break if you do not add proper headers: https://godbolt.org/z/esbhra. Relaying on `<iostream>` for other headers is a bad idea!

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <cstdio>
  
#define protect(var) \
  auto &var ## _ref = var; \
  const auto &var = var ## _ref

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) 
  {
    {
      protect(i);
      // do something with i
      //
      printf("%d\n", i);
      i = 42; // error!! remove this and it compiles.
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note: we need to nest the scope because of an astonishing stupidity in the language: the variable declared in the `for(...)` header is considered to be at the same nesting level as variables declared in the `{...}` compound statement. This means that, for instance:

```
for (int i = ...)
{
  int i = 42; // error: i redeclared in same scope
}
```

What? Didn't we just open a curly brace? Moreover, it's inconsistent:

```
void fun(int i)
{
  int i = 42; // OK
}
```

Comment: This is easily the best answer. Leveraging C++'s 'variable shadowing' to cause the identifier to resolve to a const ref variable referencing the original step variable, is an elegant solution. Or at least, the most elegant one available.

Answer (score 4):

One simple approach not yet mentioned here that works in any version of C++ is to create a functional wrapper around a range, similar to what `std::for_each` does to iterators. The user is then responsible for passing in a functional argument as a callback which will be invoked on each iteration.

For example:

```cpp
// A struct that holds the start and end value of the range
struct numeric_range
{
    int start;
    int end;

    // A simple function that wraps the 'for loop' and calls the function back
    template <typename Fn>
    void for_each(const Fn& fn) const {
        for (auto i = start; i < end; ++i) {
            const auto& const_i = i;
            fn(const_i); // or fn(std::as_const(i)); in C++17
        }
    }
};
```

Where the use would be:

```cpp
numeric_range{0, 10}.for_each([](const auto& i){
   std::cout << i << " ";  // ok
   //i = 100;              // error
});
```

Anything older than C++11 would be stuck passing a strongly-named function pointer into `for_each` (similar to `std::for_each`), but it still works.

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qT8E5K)

---

Although this may not be idiomatic for `for` loops in *C++*, this approach is quite common in other languages. Functional wrappers are really sleek for their composability in complex statements and can be very ergonomic for use.

This code is also simple to write, understand, and maintain.

Comment: One limitation to be aware of with this approach is that some organizations ban default captures on lambdas (e.g. `[&]` or `[=]`) to be compliant with certain safety standards, which may bloat the lambda with each member needing to be captured manually. Not all organizations do this, so I'm only mentioning this as a comment rather than in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T = int, class F>
void while_less(T n, F f, T start = 0){
    for(; start < n; ++start)
        f(start);
}

int main()
{
    int s = 0;
    
    while_less(10, [&](auto i){
        s += i;
    });
    
    assert(s == 45);
}
```

maybe call it `for_i`

No overhead https://godbolt.org/z/e7asGj

Comment: Not making the argument of the lambda `auto const i` really seems to defeat the point...!

Comment: @underscore_d the point was to make the counter variable not modifiable in the loop, which is `start` in my example.
Whether you want `i` `const` or not is up to you, since it's not the point, though a nice bonus.