# How to have a auto for loops, alternative to nested for loops?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, auto, std

I am wondering if there is something available in C++ which helps us to iterate over the two nested loops while using `auto`. Say like, I would want to compare an array element with all other elements forward. This is how we do it traditionally:

```
std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4};

for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) 
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); ++j) 
    {
        if (vec[i] == vec[j]) {}
        // Compares 1 with 2, 3 and 4
        // Compares 2 with 3 and 4
    }
}
```

The intention is to use **`auto`** in order to achieve this.

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4};

for (<auto>& i : vec)
//   ^^^^^^^
{
    // What should I write here so that I compare only the forward elements?
}
```

We can probably use something like this:

```
for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    for (auto jt = it + 1; jt != vec.end(); ++jt) 
    {
        // Do a comparison here.
    }
}
```

And the third snapshot again writes more code. I am looking to get more insights on the plain second snapshot.

Mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: virtually everything in the standard library is designed around using iterators, which doesn't fit with your use of loops (regardless of using `auto`).

Comment: If you are really focused on having one loop :You could first make a function that allows access to pairs of indices and then you can loop over that list of pairs : https://onlinegdb.com/c_30co3rL. Not really efficient, so I don't see any problem with either your first solution (just use indices) or with the iterator version (which is less likely to go out of bounds)

Comment: You could write a helper wrapping an array, that would be iterated over with `for ( : )` in the way you expect (check out "range adapters").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is something available in C++ which helps us to iterate over the two nested loops while using `auto`.

Not exactly what you wished for; However, with [`std::ranges::iota_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view) (Since [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)), you could write nested range-based `for` loops like follows:

```
#include <ranges> // std::ranges::iota_view

for (const auto i : std::views::iota(0u, std::size(vec)))
{
    for (const auto j : std::views::iota(i + 1u, std::size(vec)))
    {
        if (vec[i] == vec[j])
        {
            // .....
        }
    }
}
```

[See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ke17oE818)

Additionally, this enables you to have `i` and `j` be `const` over the loop scope.

---

**Side note**: For compilers older than C++20, [one could easily implement an iterator that act exactly like `std::ranges::iota_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399816/how-to-make-a-for-loop-variable-const-with-the-exception-of-the-increment-statem/63400312#63400312).

Answer (score 1):

In c++20, something like this, perhaps?

```
#include <span>

/*...*/ 

std::size_t offset = 0;

for (auto &i: vec) 
{
    for (auto &j: std::span(vec).subspan(++offset)) 
    {
        if (i == j) {}
        // Compares 1 with 2, 3 and 4
        // Compares 2 with 3 and 4           
    }
}
```

`offset` is guaranteed to be always `<= vec.size()`, hence `subspan()` is [well defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/subspan).

If you don't want to introduce a new variable, this would also work, but might produce more verbose assembly and look quite unusual:

```
for (auto &i: vec) 
{
    for (auto &j: std::span(vec).subspan(&i - vec.data() + 1)) 
    {
        if (i == j) {}
        // Compares 1 with 2, 3 and 4
        // Compares 2 with 3 and 4           
    }
}
```

For the shortest assembly, having the outer loop iterate over a span already is the best, so that the span doesn't have to be constructed at each outer iteration.

```
std::span span(vec);
std::size_t offset = 0;

for (auto &i: span) 
{
    for (auto &j: span.subspan(++offset)) 
    {
        if (i == j) {}
        // Compares 1 with 2, 3 and 4
        // Compares 2 with 3 and 4           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::any_of` in your loop. Something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

...

std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2};
for(auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    cout << std::any_of(it + 1, vec.end(), [it](int x){ return x == *it;});
}
```

this produces an output `01000`

Comment: You assume OP wants to stop after a matching element, which might not be the case.

Comment: `it+1` can go out of bounds so it is not safe to use.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it+1 will eventually become vec.end() then first == last so the lambda will not be called

Answer (score 0):

Declare a SuperIterator class of members the two iterators :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class SuperIterator {
public :
  SuperIterator (std::vector<int>::iterator beg, const std::vector<int>::iterator& end) : i_ (beg), j_ (beg), end_ (end) {}
  ~SuperIterator () {}
  SuperIterator (const SuperIterator& i) : i_ (i.i_), j_ (i.j_), end_ (i.end_) {}
  bool operator == (const SuperIterator& i) const {return (i_ == i.i_) && (j_ == i.j_);}
  bool operator != (const SuperIterator& i) const {return !operator == (i);}
  SuperIterator& operator = (const SuperIterator& i) {i_ = i.i_; j_ = i.j_;return *this;}
  void operator ++ () {
    ++j_; 
    if (j_ == end_) {
      ++i_;
      j_ = i_;
    }
  }
//private :
  std::vector<int>::iterator i_, j_;
  const std::vector<int>::iterator& end_;
};
```

Usage :

```
int main (int argc, char* []) {
  std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
  SuperIterator superbeg (vec.begin (), vec.end ()), superend (vec.end (), vec.end ());
  for (auto i (superbeg); i != superend; ++i) {
    std::cout << *i.i_ << "." << *i.j_ << "    ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

displays expected results :
1.1   1.2   1.3   1.4   2.2   2.3   2.4   3.3   3.4   4.4

just one loop using an auto iterator